# Converting an object from a NSMutableArray - objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I'm new to objective-c and havent programmed since my college days 8 years ago.

I wondering how do i convert an object from a mutable array to a integer so i can do a calculation to it.

```
NSMutableArray *years = [NSArray  arrayWithObjects:@"1800",@"1801",@"1899",@"1900",@"2000",@"2001",@"2003",@"2010",nil];

int count;
count = years.count;

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
{
   NSLog(@"The year %@ ", [years objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `NSString` documentation.

To convert the objects in your `NSMutableArray` to an integer, just do

```
[[years objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Also, you define `years` as an `NSMutableArray` but then you create an `NSArray`. You're first line should be

```
NSMutableArray *years = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1800",@"1801",@"1899",@"1900",@"2000",@"2001",@"2003",@"2010",nil];
```

And finally, a better way to iterate through the array would be like this:

```
for(NSString *a in years){
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would look at the NSString class reference, which will tell you that there's an `intValue` message you can pass strings. If your strings are valid numbers, you'll get an `int` back.

For instance, you could do something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(NSString* str in years) {
    sum += [str intValue];
}
```

Comment: For the case of summing, Cocoa offers a shortcut in `NSInteger sum = [[years valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.integerValue"] integerValue]`.

Comment: It was a contrived example. :)

Comment: @chuck, you should have put your comment as an answer...The power of cocoa KVC is enormous, but unknown...

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: The thing is, KVC is great for the cases it was designed for, but that comes at the expense of having some things it just can't do. For summing, KVC is handy. But the question wasn't really about summing — that was just the example he used.

Answer (score 0):

For example, however there is no error handling involved:

```
...
int sum;

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
{
   sum += [(NSString *)[years objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation of NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), there is also a method to convert a string into a float(floatValue).